# how to change the size of UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UILabel coded programmatically. I want to change the size of the label when i pressed a button. how to change the size of that label? this is my code

```
 UILabel *theLabel11 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];  
[theLabel11 setText:@"US"];
[theLabel11 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[theLabel11 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0f]];
[theLabel11 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[theLabel11 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scroll1 addSubview:theLabel11];
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should declare your label as class property, so it can be accessed from other methods

To change the font size use

```
[theLabel11 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0f]];
```

To change the frame size of the label us

```
theLabel11.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 12):

A common idiom for adjusting the spatial information on a UIView is as below

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(
    x,
    y,
    width,
    height
);
```

You can get the old position and height via

```
label.frame.origin.x
label.frame.origin.y
label.frame.size.width
label.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one label added to scroll1 then, iterate the scrollview to get the label reference as follows in button action

```
for(UIView *subView in scroll1.subViews){

if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)subView;
//change size of label here
}
}
```

if there are many labels assign a tag to each label while creating and check that in for loop

Comment: ...or forget that loop and better use viewWithTag: