# Label with sizetoFit keeps getting smaller

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
self.Label.text = self.texts[arc4random_uniform(5)];
[self.Label sizeToFit];
[self.Label setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f]];
```

This runs everytime there's a swipe on screen.

Problem: for everytime the label rectangle gets smaller and smaller!

This is seemingly caused by the 'sizeToFit', as the problem goes away when I put that line as a comment

Comment: Could easily be a rounding issue. Sizetofit should give best results if you provide a large size to begin with (e.g. max width for wrapping). But besides that, in this situation it would be better to give a sufficient initial size, and not resize each frame

Comment: Well the purpose here is to put a text onto some background, and cover as little as possible. So for the shortests textpieces I don't want the label to fill more than necessary
a rounding issue? can you explain

Comment: I'm not on a machine where I can test, but it sounds like the text is (say) 44.1 pixels wide, so is given 44 pixels. Next time, the text is cropped to 44 pixels, so it squashes to 43.9 pixels, so is given 43 pixels, etc. there are a lot of config options which would control this (text can crop, squash, truncate, wrap, etc.) so it may depend on your exact setup.

Comment: You can get around that by setting an explicit (large) size before calling sizeToFit, giving you deterministic results.

Comment: Interesting! would I set that explicit size in the code? so that for everytime code runs size is first set to large size then 'sizeToFit'. Or could I do this from within storyboard?

Comment: It would need to be in the code, but you could store the size when the screen first loads and reset it to that each time, allowing you to change it from within the storyboard.

Comment: Honestly I'm completely new and wouldn't know how to do what you're suggesting. Any tips on what to search for? I was thinking that I could set the label size to specific width/height values right above the sizeToFit - if so, I just need to find out how to set labelsize = width: height:  - or similar

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way. I assumed you wanted to set it from the storyboard, but if you're happy hard-coding the values, go for it.

Comment: hmm, possible misunderstanding. I'm currently searching around trying to find some command to set the label size in the code. I missed how I can set this in the storyboard?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6080677/1180785

Comment: Thanks a lot man! that all ended up working out for me!